# Task queue: Allow only one task at a time per user

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

In my application, I need to allow only one task at a time per user. I have seen that we can set `max_concurrent_requests: 1` in `queue.yaml`. but this will allows only one task at a time in a queue.

When a user click a button, a task will be initiated and it will add 50 task to the queue. If 2 user click the button in almost same time total task count will be 100. If i give `max_concurrent_requests: 1` it will run only one task from any of these user.

How do i handle this situation ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.  If you set `max_concurrent_requests: 1` and add 2 lots of 50 tasks, they will be executed, one at a time, at the rate specified in your queue definition and in the order in which they were enqueued. Task Queues have no concept of users. If you want to find out how many tasks are the on queue, try `Queue.fetch_statistics()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify as many queues as you like in queue.yaml rather than just using the default push queue. If you feel that no more than, say, five users at once are likely to contest for simultaneous use of them then simply define five queues. Have a global counter that increases by one and wraps back to 1 when it exceeds five. Use it to assign which queue a given user gets to push his or her tasks to at the time of the request. With this method, when you have six or more users concurrently adding tasks, you are no worse off than you currently are (in fact, likely much better off).

If you find the server overloading, turn down the default "rate: 5/s" to a lower value for some or all of the queues if you have to, but first try lowering the bucket size, because turning down the rate is going to slow things down when there are not multiple users. Personally, I would first try only turning down the four added queues and leave the first queue fast to solve this if you have performance issues that you can't resolve by tuning the bucket sizes.

Comment: @tx802 yes, your comment makes me realize that simply cycling the queues is kind of silly. I would fetch the statistics for each queue in turn until I found an empty one. If none are empty I would use the least loaded one.